# How can I get the text between 2 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="link">asd</a>
  [I want get this text]
  <a href="#" class="link">asd</a>
  Anouther text i dont need.
</div>
```

How can I withdraw the text between  elements (not the inner text of  elements, in this case I should get "[I want get this text]")?

Comment: The text blocks are also nodes in the DOM tree, and would show up as part of the div.container's childNodes

Comment: `firstAnchor.nextSibling.data` where `firstAnchor` is a reference to the fist A element.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I didn't thought that pure text is also a node in DOM

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/btqBe/)

I think the simplest way would be to deal with the native dom elements:

```
var a = $(".container a")[0];
var textNode = a.nextSibling;
var text = textNode.textContent;
```

Note that `var text = textNode.nodeValue;` will also work, but I'm not sure which is preferable.

Comment: This doesn't work if the text you want is in multiple nodes between the two nodes. In my case I had some `<br>` tags in the text and this reads only up to the first `<br>` tag.

Answer (score -1):

One way is to enclose the part in a span tag and get the contents of the span:

```
<div class="container">
      <a href="#" class="link">asd</a>
      <span id="i_want_this">[I want get this text]</span>
      <a href="#" class="link">asd</a>
      Anouther text i dont need.
</div>

myVal = $("#i_want_this").html();
```

Comment: If i could do this, i wouldn't be asking this question ;]